# MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel 4.2 error

Tags: php, laravel-4, migration

here is my ContactController.php:

```
public function destroy($id){
    $contact = Contact::find($id);
    $contact->delete();
    return Redirect::to('http://localhost:8000/contactsview');
}
```

Here is my rountes.php

```
Route::delete('/contactsview/destroy/{id}', array('uses'=>'ContactController@destroy'));
```

Here is my index.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'/contactsview/delete/'.$contact->id, 'method'=>'DELETE', 'style'=>'display:inline;')) }}
<!-- {{ Form::hidden('id', $contact->id) }} -->
{{ Form::submit('Delete') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the form with this instead, passing in the `$contact->id` as a param rather than directly in the URL:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => array('ContactController@destroy', $contact->id )) }}
```